# How to disable systemd journald from listening to syslog socket

Tags: embedded-linux, systemd, rsyslog

Overview: 
In linux based embedded system with systemd , we have journal which takes care of logging and it is very advanced and handy. It by default listen to syslog socket and kernel message as well. Since we have rsyslog also running on the system syslog messages are getting duplicated both in systemd journal as well as rsyslog file.

Query:
Is there some way we could make the journal not to listen to syslog socket.

Note:
From my understand and observation there is no way to configure this in journald configure file.

Answer (score 1):

If your system takes systemd as init system, then systemd-journald is launched by systemd by default.
Since you said "syslog messages are getting **duplicated** both in systemd journal as well as rsyslog file", that means journald is forwarding syslog to rsyslog, it's not both daemons are listening to syslog socket. Only journald is listening to that socket. Rsyslog gets the log forwarded to it by journald.

Comment: You explained why the problem exists. You should add an actual solution to your answer. Please see [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the port number on which journal is listening

How to configure Journald

https://serverfault.com/questions/758244/how-to-configure-systemd-journal-remote